# onsenui - What is the purpose of the black mask?

Tags: onsen-ui

I would like to try to create a popup using ons.screen.presentPage() with a transparent background, however once the transition is complete there is a black mask that appears behind the page. Could you please indicate the purpose of this black mask or the best way to create a popup dialog / selector?

Answer (score 1):

The black mask is used to achieve the fade out effect of the exiting page.

What you can do, is to use DOM api to hide it.

ex.

```
// the controller of the entering page
function Page2Controller($scope){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.onsen_screen-black-mask').hide();
    }, 0);
}
```